# Python, как из списка удалить часть строки у каждого элемента?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Мне нужно, чтобы из этого списка

```
image_list = ['image\\TestPh.jpg', 'image\\376ot.jpg', 'image\\3ugu.jpg', 'image\\inypf.jpg', 'image\\vqhxt.jpg', 'image\\wqfgb.jpg']
```

Осталось только это:

```
image_list = ['TestPh.jpg', '376ot.jpg', '3ugu.jpg', 'inypf.jpg', 'vqhxt.jpg', 'wqfgb.jpg']
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы только часть удалилась в каждом элементе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать *списковое сокращение* и функцию `split`:

```
image_list = ['image\\TestPh.jpg', 'image\\376ot.jpg', 'image\\3ugu.jpg', 'image\\inypf.jpg', 'image\\vqhxt.jpg', 'image\\wqfgb.jpg']
image_list = [x.split('\\')[1] for x in image_list]
print(image_list)
```

Вывод:

```
['TestPh.jpg', '376ot.jpg', '3ugu.jpg', 'inypf.jpg', 'vqhxt.jpg', 'wqfgb.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь просто использовать метод replace:

```
image_list = [x.replace('image\\', '') for x in image_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь использовать метод rstrip():

```
image_list = [string.rstrip('image\\') for string in image_list]
```